# SQL Server Replication - Duplicate subscription agents?

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-replication

I am new to SQL Server replication, and pushed some changes out to an existing replicated environment. It is SQL Server 2005 SP3, with Transactional replication.
I created a new table, added columns to an existing table, and added some SPs.  I did all of this on the publisher database.
I created a new snapshot and reinitialized the subscriptions.  The new table and new columns were replicated to the new server, and data was synchronized successfully, but just 1 time.

Immediately after, the replication monitor is reporting an error. On the Distributor to Subscriber History tab, I get a message that the "Subquery returned more than 1 value". The Command Attempted is...

```t-sql
delete from MSsubscription_articlecolumns
    where artid=89 and
          agent_id = (
              select id from MSsubscription_agents
                  where update_mode > 0 and
                        UPPER(publisher) = UPPER('xxxx') and
                        publisher_db = N'xxxx' and
                        publication = N'xxxxx'
              ) end
```

Why would there be duplicate subscription agents?  How do I fix this?  Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by manually editing the data in the MSsubscription_agents table.  There were 2 records with the same publisher, db and publication names.  Instead of deleting one of the records, I changed the update_mode on the older record to be 0, which filtered it out of the problem statement in original question.  The replication process was then able to get past that statement and run correctly.  Thanks.